# jQuery - Filtering unique icon sources

Tags: jquery, image, filter, unique

I have a list of images and I want to filter out the icons based on width, and store in a variable 'icons'. This part is done with no issues. I am then trying to filter out the icons with duplicate sources, so I only get the unique icons in the 'icons' variable, and append it to the uniq div.

I found this code, which removes duplicate all duplicate images on load. I can't get it to run after the 'icons' have been filtered first before being appended to the uniq div:

```
$(function(){
var srcs = [], temp;
    $("img").filter(function(){
        temp = $(this).attr("src");
        if($.inArray(temp, srcs) < 0){
            srcs.push(temp);   
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }).remove();
});
```

Here is what I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/xCjjp/9/

Any idea how to get filtered 'icons' to keep only unique sources before appending them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you're looping through your images to add them to `div#uniq` add every new image source to an array and check each consecutive source against that array, if it isn't there, that means it's unique.

```
var icons = $("img").filter(function(){
    return (this.width < 100)
});
    var icon_src = [];

$.each(icons, function(i,e){
    if ($.inArray(e.src, icon_src) === -1) {
        $("#uniq").append("<img src='"+ e.src +"'>");
        icon_src.push(e.src);
    }
});
```

You can find it working here http://jsfiddle.net/KhWgj/4/